# Digicam as recording device

Tags: video

Are there digicams with HDMI out, so that I can connect the digicam to a TV card in my computer and record directly, what the digicam sees? Also the digicam then of course shouldn't go into any kind of standby while recording. Thanks for any hint :-)

Answer (score 2):

When I plug a Nikon J1 into my TV using an HDMI cable the TV displays the live-preview that is normally shown on the LCD on the back of the camera. I expect I could configure the camera not to sleep and (possibly) not to display settings as an onscreen overlay. If I instead pluggedt the HDMI into a recording device I am sure I could record that (HDCP notwithstanding).

I imagine this may be true for many such cameras.

So yes, such devices exist.